# According a div size to its content

Tags: html, css

I'm currentrly creating a website, and I need to adapt the size of a div according to the offset on one of it childs.
So, I'm doing it this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        if($(sizer)[0].scrollHeight > 500)
        {
            $(maincnt).height( ($(sizer)[0].scrollHeight + 300) );
        }
      });

</script>
```

But, the problem is that event is no trigged by Firefox. But with chrome it works.
Is there a cleaner way to accord the div size ? If not, is there a way to make it trigged by Firefox ? Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="maincnt" >
<div style="position:relative;">
<div id="sizer" style="position:absolute;top:12px;left:10px;width:750px;">
   <!-- Dynamically added things -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit : I gave up, i've found another workaround which solve my first problem, not the JQuery one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that when the DOMready event is fired, all the widths and heights are not yet calculated by the browser. The DOMready event is fired when the page structure is ready to work with, not when the css has loaded.

Try to do this kind of work on the load event, which fires when all the assets of a page is loaded, css included:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    if($(sizer)[0].scrollHeight > 500) {
        $(maincnt).height( ($(sizer)[0].scrollHeight + 300) );
    }
});
```

Comment: This event isn't fired by firefox neither chrome. Look at http://178.33.232.214/ : the problem is the div which is not re-sized by its child-div content (if you have an adblocker, disbale it to see the bug).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly caused by the fact that you're treating DOM elements as if JS comes pre-populated with IDs as variables.

Try `$('#sizer')` and `$('#maincnt')` instead of the ones you currently have.

Also, why are you using an absolutely positioned element anyway? What's wrong with just having it set with: `margin: 12px 0px 0px 10px; width: 750px;`?